# Spring Data Rest: Query parameters chained with logical OR

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have an entity that is exposed by the following repository:

```
public interface InsertRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<InsertEntity, Long>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<InsertEntity>, QueryDslBinderCustomizer<QInsertEntity> {
    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QInsertEntity insert) {
        bindings.bind(String.class).all(StringPath path, Collection<? extends String> values) -> {
            BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
            values.forEach(value -> predicate.or(path.containsIgnoreCase(value)));

            return predicate;
        });
    }
}
```

What I'd like it to do is that all GET query parameters are chained as logical OR so that a query like `?description=searchText&customerName=searchText` would execute an SQL query that looks as follows:

`WHERE description LIKE '%searchText%' OR customerName LIKE '%searchText%'`

However, I must be doing something wrong because it doesn't work - it is putting all query parameters into an `AND` query. That results in only those records being selected that contain `searchText` in customerName **AND** their description.

Comment: TypeBinder$all() allows you to customize a multi-value binding that you specify by path or by class. But even when you customize a binding "by class", query parameters are not treated globally. For instance

Comment: @MarcTarin Alright, so if I understand you correctly, I cannot accomplish what I need using the `customize` method, right?

Comment: For instance `?description=searchText&description=searchInt` will give you `WHERE description LIKE '%searchText%' OR description LIKE '%searchInt%'`. OccurenceS of `customerName` are processed as a separate clause, and all clauses are joined with AND. So no, to the best of my knowledge, you can't accomplish what you need with the `customize` method.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much - guess I'll use a custom query for that.

Answer (score 1):

The answer provided by @kafkas is not accurate at all. There are quite few problems with it:

1. Annotation `@Query` is obsolette - Spring automatically does it for you, you just need to type the name of the method properly.
2. Annotations `@Param` are obsolette - Spring automatically takes parameters in given order, matched with those in method name.
3. You return single User entity, but you still use `findBy` instead of `findOne` - this leads to an error, if more than one record is found.
4. The last, but not least - provided method will not use `LIKE` comparation, but equals instead. You should use `findByXXXContaining` if You wish to launch SQL query like: `... WHERE firstname LIKE "%name%"`
5. Using Spring, I suggest not using JpaRepository if You don't need to. The simplest implementation is `CrudRepository` and it covers most use cases.

In summary, Your method should be simplified and look somewhere like that:

`public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
       User findOneByLastnameContainingOrFirstnameContaining(String lastname, String firstname);
}`

This should result in query:

`SELECT * FROM User u WHERE u.lastname LIKE '%lastname' OR u.firstname LIKE '%firstname%;'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use named parameters such as 
**Example 53. Using named parameters**

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
   @Query("select u from User u where u.firstname = :firstname or u.lastname = :lastname")
   User findByLastnameOrFirstname(@Param("lastname") String lastname,
                               @Param("firstname") String firstname);
}
```

Comment: This would require me to create a new controller method which in turn would call the method. I'm trying to expose that behaviour through the normal REST interface so I do not need to call a specific method for the query.

Comment: The framework will automatically generate a `/search/findByLastnameOrFirstname` endpoint for you.

Comment: This has some serious issues... check my answer for details.